# Error al llamar método desde OnCreate

Tags: java, android

Me aparece un error al llamar el método llenarEspecialidad, el error es:

> **java.lang.NullPointerException**: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.loopj.android.http.RequestHandle
>   com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.post(java.lang.String,
>   com.loopj.android.http.ResponseHandlerInterface)' **on a null object
>   reference**

El código es:

```
public class BusquedaEspecialista extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AsyncHttpClient especialidad;
    private RequestParams especialidadparam;
    private Spinner spEspecialidad;
    private ArrayList<Especialidad> listaEspecialidad;
    private String nomespecialidad;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_busqueda_especialista);
        spEspecialidad = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_especialidad);
        listaEspecialidad = new ArrayList<Especialidad>();

        llenarEspecialidad();
    }

    private void llenarEspecialidad() {
        String url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        especialidad.post(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                if (statusCode == 200)
                    cargarEspecialidad(new String(responseBody));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: ¿Dónde te está dando el NPE, en qué línea?  Si puedes agrega a la pregunta la traza completa del error, la puedes encontrar en el logcat.

Comment: Hola!, en la línea donde llama al método, esa es la línea que indica el exception

Comment: @RobertoHermosillaF debes inicializar el AsyncHttpClient en este caso la variable especialidad.

Answer (score 2):

Es necesario instanciar el objeto especialidad antes de usarlo

```
private void llenarEspecialidad() {
    String url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    especialidad = new AsyncHttpClient();
```

Answer (score 0):

Usas la variable `especialidad` para realizar la petición, pero necesitas inicializarla ya que esto es el problema mencionado en el `LogCat`:

```
private AsyncHttpClient especialidad;
```

Esto lo puedes realizar dentro de onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_busqueda_especialista);
    ...
    ...

    //Inicializa especialidad 
    especialidad = new AsyncHttpClient();

    llenarEspecialidad();
}
```

Revisa el cambio

```
public class BusquedaEspecialista extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AsyncHttpClient especialidad;
    private RequestParams especialidadparam;
    private Spinner spEspecialidad;
    private ArrayList<Especialidad> listaEspecialidad;
    private String nomespecialidad;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_busqueda_especialista);
        spEspecialidad = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_especialidad);
        listaEspecialidad = new ArrayList<Especialidad>();

        //Inicializa especialidad 
        especialidad = new AsyncHttpClient();

        llenarEspecialidad();
    }

    private void llenarEspecialidad() {
        String url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        especialidad.post(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                if (statusCode == 200)
                    cargarEspecialidad(new String(responseBody));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Jorge, muchas gracias! eso funcionó ok!

Comment: Excelente @RobertoHermosillaF saludos.